# Creating a reminder for field staff to rename photo attachments in ArcGIS Collector

Tags: arcgis-collector

It saves a ton of time in the office when field staff rename photo attachments directly in Collector. However, they have to remember to click on each photo and to rename it, and it's not obvious whether a photo has already been renamed, so it's often forgotten. I've thought about adding a hint to whatever the first field is that reminds staff to rename any photo attachments, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a good way to do this?